# Detecting and alerting when web.config is corrupt

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, web-config

We recently ran into a situation where a bungled web.config deployment resulted in two 'appSettings' sections in our web.config. We've got detailed error shut off (it's prod) and so in the browser we saw a generic 500 error. Checking Windows application log revealed nothing.

Is it possible to set up some kind of alerting for a case like this? Something (anything!) logged to the Windows application log would be ideal.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: By default is logged on windows log.

Comment: Shouldn't this kind of error be caught in a staging environment?  Surely you're not updating web.config settings directly in a production environment.

Comment: @Aristos we are finding that some web.config problems are reported and some are not. In this case, duplicate appSettings section is not reported in any windows log that I've seen.

Comment: @Chris Ballance imagine a scenario where the web.config must be different in prod vs. staging for whatever reason. Now imagine that the mechanism used for deploying this different web.config (be it automated or otherwise) fails for some reason, and in this case, inserts an additional appSettings section rather than updating an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an error logging module to help you debug your application. I found [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to be a very good tool. Here's how you [log errors using ELMAH](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs).

ELMAH can help you debug your application in the future. Whenever you make changes to your application, test it before publishing the changes. A good way of doing it would be to set up a Staging environment to match the Production server. That way you would be able to see any errors before moving the changes to your live application.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! We'll give it a try.

Comment: Serious question: if ELMAH uses the web.config for configuration and the web.config is broke, how can ELMAH work?

Comment: Thanks Jason -- as it happens, we confirmed ELMAH can't help for the reason you've pointed out. It requires a working web.config.